# XML map plain sequence of data to complex data array

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, position

probably the title of this post is not the best possible, but I really didn't know how to describe what I want to achieve.

The response of a service call is a xml structure like this:

```
<Document>
<kind>Data</kind>   
<rows>Chrome</rows>
<rows>Auckland</rows>
<rows>1</rows>
<rows>0</rows>
<rows>Firefox</rows>
<rows>Milan</rows>
<rows>1</rows>
<rows>0</rows>
<rows>Safari</rows>
<rows>Auckland</rows>
<rows>1</rows>
<rows>0</rows>
<rows>Safari</rows>
<rows>Milan</rows>
<rows>1</rows>
<rows>0</rows>
</Document>
```

(*the number of rows in not fixed)

I need to transform that in something like this:

```
<Document>   
<Row>
<Field_0>Chrome</Field_0>
<Field_1>Auckland</Field_1>
<Field_2>1</Field_2>
<Field_3>0</Field_3>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field_0>Firefox</Field_0>
<Field_1>Milan</Field_1>
<Field_2>1</Field_2>
<Field_3>0</Field_3>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field_0>Safari</Field_0>
<Field_1>Auckland</Field_1>
<Field_2>1</Field_2>
<Field_3>0</Field_3>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field_0>Safari</Field_0>
<Field_1>Milan</Field_1>
<Field_2>1</Field_2>
<Field_3>0</Field_3>
</Row>
</Document>
```

As you see there's a patter, the target structure is build by position, not by name.
I am using a framework that allows me to use XSLT (no Java code!).

Is there any one that can point me to the right direction?
A queried google, but probably not knowing how to describe what I want to achieve, I couldn't find any help.

Thanks, Giovanni

Comment: You seem to know that there are 4 fields per row. I see no such indication in the given input - unless one is a human and  knows how to make an educated guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following XSLT iterates on rows, storing the positions required to create field names in variables, forming Row elements with fields inside:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="rows">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 1">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="relativePos" select="($pos mod 4) - 1"/>
                <Row>
                    <xsl:element name="Field_{$relativePos}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Field_{$relativePos + 1}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../rows[$pos + 1]"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Field_{$relativePos + 2}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../rows[$pos + 2]"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Field_{$relativePos + 3}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../rows[$pos + 3]"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </Row>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do in document level:

```
<apply-template select="rows[position() mod 4 = 1]" /> <!-- Selecting only rows 1, 5, 9... -->
```

and in the rows template:

```
<Row>
  <xsl:element name="Field_0">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="Field_1">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::rows[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="Field_2">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::rows[2]"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="Field_3">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::rows[3]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</Row>
```

Posted as i found other post quite complicated for a such simple problem.